# Running selenium webdriver C# test with Microsoft.Expression.Encoder from command line

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, browser-automation

I am working on a Selenium webdriver based C# NUnit project, where I have several tests which take screenshots and record video of each test scenario using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.dll.
I'm planning to run these tests from command line using the below code sample.

```
nunit-console /run:MyProject.Tests.SampleTest MyProject.dll
```

As my project is built on .NET Framework 4.0, I did updated the config file for nunit to use framework 4.0 using the below line of setting.

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
```

My issue is, when i try to run a test, i get below error. I tried building the project in x86 and x64 mode, but the issue remains.

> Errors and Failures: 
>   1) Test Error : MyProject.Tests.SampleTest 
>      System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I also tried to run a simple test, which runs fine from command line.

Comment: Sounds like it is being compiled in a different architecture than what you are running at. What are you compiling the test library under? Any CPU? x86?

Comment: I tried compiling under Any CPU, x86 and x64. Every time with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. As I am using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder DLL in my project to video record a test, this DLL is compiled as x86. Thus I can keep my selenium C# project in Any CPU mode and use the below command to execute tests.

```
nunit-console-x86 /run:MyProject.Tests.SampleTest MyProject.dll
```

Nunit folder has two "nunit-console" exes *(**nunit-console.exe** and **nunit-console-x86.exe**)*